# Multiple Column to Row

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, lambda

[Raw data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tMGTh.png) 
I have data in datatable as per the first image but want to convert my datatable or create a new datatable with new output which is in 2nd image

```
                var reportData = (from C in Table1
                                  join LC in Table2 on C.Id equals LC.Id
                                  select new { C.Id, C.User, LC.Phy, LC.Che, LC.Bio, LC.Math }).ToList();

                foreach (var item in reportData)
                {

                    lstLc.Add(new Launch() { Username= item.User, Phy = item.Phy, Che = item.Che, Bio = item.Bio, Math = item.Math });
        }
```

Raw data:[Output needed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/20kMP.png)

```
User    Phy    Che    Bio    Math
A       12     20     16     10
B       15     19     18     20
C       13     17     11     18
```

Output needed..

```
User    Type    value
A       Phy     12
A       Che     20
A       Bio     16
A       Math    10
B       Phy     15
B       Che     19
B       Bio     18
B       Math    20
C       Phy     13
C       Che     17
C       Bio     11
C       Math    18
```

Comment: what is the question ?

Comment: I have data in datatable as per the first image but want to convert my datatable or create a new datatable with new output which is in 2nd image.

Comment: do you understand that this is a request and not a question to a problem ? and not only that but you also do not even give some code to work with. where's that data lives on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `union` like this:

```
SELECT User, Type, value FROM (
    SELECT User, 'Phy' AS 'Type', Phy AS 'value' FROM table1
    UNION
    SELECT User, 'Che' AS 'Type', Che AS 'value' FROM table1
    UNION
    SELECT User, 'Bio' AS 'Type', Bio AS 'value' FROM table1
    UNION
    SELECT User, 'Math' AS 'Type', Math AS 'value' FROM table1
) AS t
ORDER BY User
```

In LINQ you can do something like this:

```
var list = entity.Select(e => new { User = e.User, Type = "Phy", value = e.Phy })
    .Union(entity.Select(e => new { User = e.User, Type = "Che", value = e.Che }))
    .Union(entity.Select(e => new { User = e.User, Type = "Bio", value = e.Bio }))
    .Union(entity.Select(e => new { User = e.User, Type = "Math", value = e.Math }))
    .OrderBy(e => e.User);
```

**Edit** change your code to this:

```
var repFlatData = (from C in Table1
                   join LC in Table2 on C.Id equals LC.Id
                   select new { C.Id, C.User, LC.Phy, LC.Che, LC.Bio, LC.Math }).ToList();

var reportData = repFlatData.Select(e => new { User = e.User, Type = "Phy", value = e.Phy })
          .Union(repFlatData.Select(e => new { User = e.User, Type = "Che", value = e.Che }))
          .Union(repFlatData.Select(e => new { User = e.User, Type = "Bio", value = e.Bio }))
          .Union(repFlatData.Select(e => new { User = e.User, Type = "Math", value = e.Math }))
          .OrderBy(e => e.User);

foreach (var item in reportData) {
    lstLc.Add(new Launch() { Username= item.User, Type = item.Type, Value = item.Value });
}
```

Of course, you'll need to change your `Launch` class to only have the columns (Username, Type, Value).

Comment: I want this in ASP.net using Lambda query not in SQL.

Comment: Thnks Racil. I have edited my question and also write the actual code in C#. So could u plz help me on the same code. As i am new to Asp.net.

Comment: See my edited answer.

Comment: Thnx a lot Racil.. It works now...